# Hide a tag after span css

Tags: html, css

I need to hide `<a>` tag coming after `<span>` there is no class available on `<a>` and I am working on a script coming from third party so i just need to hide `<a>` script using css, I have no much knowledge about css so please let me know. I think this can be done using css.

```
<span class = "hidea">abc</span>
<a href = ""> hide me </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `adjacent sibling selector (+)` which will select the specified element that immediately follows the former one

```css
.hidea + a { display: none; }
```

```html
<span class = "hidea">abc</span>
<a href = ""> hide me </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the adjacent sibling selector (+)

```
.hidea + a { display: none; }
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

> [...] It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector

```
.hidea + a{
   display:none;
}
```